# java program a infinite loop in thread cause hundred percent cpu

Tags: java, loops

I am quite new to Threads in Java, I am using an API which is using thread internally and listening data from the counter party, I am putting this data in an queue for further processing. I have created another Thread which is continuously reading this queue for retrieving data and processing and to write the results into text file. I am using while(true) statement to run infinite loop in thread this cause a hundred per cent of CPU usage and if I use sleep(10) in it add up latency which keep on increasing with time as I am receiving about 20 data item in one second.

```
public void run() { 
    while(true) { 
      try { Thread.sleep(10); } 
      catch (InterruptedException e2) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e2.printStackTrace(); 
     } 
     if (!(queue.isEmpt())) { 
        Tick quote=queue.take(); 
        processTuple(quote); 
     } 
    } // end while(true) 
  } // end run()
```

Could anyone suggest me solution where I can reduce CPU usage without adding latency.

Comment: show code in order to help ..

Comment: Following is my run method code

Comment: public void run() {
   
   while(true) {
    
    try {
     Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e2.printStackTrace();
    }
     if (!(queue.isEmpt())) {
     Tick quote=queue.take();
     processTuple(quote);
    }
      
   
   } // end while(true)
  } // end run()

Comment: @Zafar Iqbal: Edit your question and insert the code there, indented 4 spaces, and it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).

**EDIT**:

Example of how to use a queue based on your code:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Tick> queue;

public void run() { 
    while (true) {
        // No need to check the queue. No need to sleep().
        // take() will wait until there's anything available
        Tick quote = queue.take();
        processTuple(quote);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya. Use a `BlockingQueue` implementation instead of *busy- wait*. `while(true)` will keep scheduling the thread.

Comment: I am already using LinkedBlockingQueue type of queue.       
 Sorry I did not get here...could you please give me more hint ....how can I achieve reading from a queue continuously without using while(true) statement in a Thread. Please advise much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use `queue` implementations instead of `Threads`. See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html) to know more about queue implementations. You can use `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: Sorry I did not get here...could you please give me more hint ....how can I achieve reading from a queue continuously without using while(true) statement in a Thread. Please advise much appreciated

Comment: Don't use threads here. You'll have to use white true though. Queue's have certain methods to check if it's full or empty. You can see how consume and produce methods are writteh to manipulate queue. https://github.com/jeevan-patil/thread/blob/master/src/org/thread/blockqueue/ProduceConsume.java

Comment: @Jeevan Patil 웃: Why do you say "don't use threads"? For me, that's the point with queues. The example you point to uses threads.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson OP said that he is using thread to continuously read data from the queue. We don't need threads to do that. Simple while(true) loop can do that.

Comment: @Jeevan Patil 웃: The minimum is one thread to read (consume) from a queue. In that sense you don't need threads, but you need another thread to produce to the queue. And most likely, you have more than one consumer, and my guess is that that is what OP is doing. He still needs threads. Each thread usually needs a while(true) loop though. The OP's problem was however a miss-use of the queue. Compare the code in my edited answer with OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You may change your code something like this:

```
BlockingQueue<Tick> queue = ..

public void run() 
{ 
  for (Tick quote; quote = queue.take(); )
  { 
    if (quote == someSpecialObjectToIndicateStop) 
       break; // To stop this thread Or you may catch InterruptedException

    processTuple(quote); 
  } 
}
```

See BlockingQueue documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)